# SQL Split text from column in several lines in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I'm creating a job in SQL Server 2014 and the last step is to send the output of the first step to my email. I'm already sending the email with the result of the next query:

```
select TOP 1 
    msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) as 'RunDateTime', 
    message 
from 
    sysjobhistory 
where 
    job_id = 'SOMETHING' and step_id = 1
order by 
    run_date DESC, run_time DESC
```

The `message` column has a big text and it outputs all in one line as you can see in this image:

[image: Example of the email received]

I want to know if it's possible to split the text into several lines. I can do it based in a delimiter. I saw some functions but all they do is to separate the text in columns and rows and I don't want that.

Thank you :)

Comment: I format such results as HTML for email purposes.  However, such an effort is too detailed (at least for me) to put into a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: How are you planning to decide where to split the line?

Comment: I cant split by the substring "Executed" @TomH

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you show me just a simple formating so I could start trying that approach?

Comment: if it's a normal text you can replace the delimiter by char(13)

Comment: But how can I do it in that query? Because I'm not the one populating this table, it's from the sql system. @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "Executed:" turns up a bunch in the string, so I might start with something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) as 'RunDateTime',
    REPLACE(message, 'Executed:', CHAR(13) + 'Executed:') AS message
FROM
    sysjobhistory
WHERE
    job_id = 'SOMETHING' and step_id = 1
ORDER BY
    run_date DESC,
    run_time DESC
```

Comment: I like `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`

Comment: Yes, depending on how you'll be viewing the text it might work better with 13-10 rather than just 13.